# Hypothesis testing in Linear Discriminant Analysis

Tags: hypothesis-testing, discriminant-analysis

In order to check dependency between a categorical independent variable and a numerical dependent variable, one applies analysis of variance. If the dependency is vice versa, i.e., a categorical dependent variable and a numeric independent variable, which approach can I apply? For modeling and prediction purposes I can use Linear (Quadratic) Discriminant Analysis, but how can I check the hypothesis of independence?

Comment: Was this helpful?

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question, then you want to know how to model a categorical dependent variable with a continuous independent variable.

In the case of a bivariate outcome, you use [logistic regression](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logistic_regression). If you have more than two categories, you can consider [multinomial regression](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multinomial_logistic_regression). If your data is count data, then you would want to look at [Poisson regression](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poisson_regression).

These are all types of [General Linear Model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/General_linear_model) (GLM), and will give you confidence intervals and pvalues.

Pretty much any statistical package should be able perform these for you. They are all very simple to do in R.

Comment: I would add, you can also use LDA/MDA/ QDA or other algorithms such as SVM, decision tree, random forest, ANN, etc. but you need to understand the algorithm & its assumptions to be able to do